# Unpack a binary file to a text file - A problem that flips the values

Tags: perl

How can I unpack a 4byte binary file, store like the following example,
to array or TEXT file ?

input file:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000001  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01  |................|
```

desired output file:

```
0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
```

For now I'm using the following unpack code:

```
open(ERROR_ID_BIN, "<", "/error_id.bin") or die $!;
local $/;
my @err_values = unpack("V*", <ERROR_ID_BIN>); 
close(ERROR_ID_BIN);
print "\n\n\n\n\t@err_values\n\n\n";
```

And my problem is that it flips the values and gives me that:

```
0,16777216,16777216,0,16777216,16777216,16777216,16777216
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V is little-endian (least significant byte first); try N for big-endian (most significant byte first).

Comment: Heh, I had that problem once. Took me days to figure it out.
Now I always check with little&big endian if something's wrong

Answer (score 3):

From the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) documentation

> N An unsigned long (32-bit) in
> "network" (big-endian) order.
>
> V An
> unsigned short (32-bit) in "VAX"
> (little-endian) order.

Don't you want 'N' to correct your *endness* ?

Comment: Yes, 'N' change the result to the expected result.